# How to check type of soup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code

```
soup.find("class":"gtx")
```

How to check type of this soup in python ?

Answer (score 1):

First create a variable.

```
ty= soup.find("class":"gtx")

print(type(ty))
```

Comment: Thanks Farhan. Can please tell me how to make integer to string this soup